# Populating a line graph from csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to pull information from a csv file and populating my line graph in d3.  I'm basing the format of my code heavily from: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Here's my actual code to pull information from my csv file:

```
d3.csv("population.csv", function(error, data) {

    // convert your csv data and add it to dataSet
    var color = d3.scale.category10();
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {return key !== "year";}));

    var census = color.domain().map(function(name) {
         return {
              name: name,
              values: data.map(function(d) {
                   return {year: d.year, population: +d[name]};  
              })
         };  
    });
```

My CSV data is structured like this:

```
year, population1, population2, population3, population4, population5
0, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000
```

(these are just sample numbers, I viewed it via excel and it looks alright).

However, when I run it through the local host, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function n(n){n.each(function(){var n,s=Xo.select(this),l=this.__chart__||e,f=this.__chart__=e.copy(),h=null==c?f.ticks?f.ticks.apply(f,a):f.domain():c,g=null==t?f.tickFormat?f.tickFormat.apply(f,a):bt:t,p=s.selectAll(".t...<omitted>...x'
```

And it is triggered by this chunk of code, which looks relatively harmless, so I suspect it has to do with my pulling the csv data in the first place.

```
  var line = d3.svg.axis()
       //.interpolate("basis")
       .x(function(d) {return x(d.year); })
       .y(function(d) {return y(d.population); })
```

Comment: Is the second chunk of code contained inside the callback of the first chunk? Are you hosting the `.csv` file via a local webserver?

Comment: also, should it not be `{return key !== "year1"...`?

Comment: Second chunk of code is located beneath first chunk of code.  I call to access the csv file first and then attempt to draw a line.  Csv file is hosted via local webserver.

Comment: FernoftheAndes - nice catch, I drew out my data incorrectly, year is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update.  This problem is resolved.  As it turns out, there were multiple things that were triggering the error in the code.  Two major things were (cannot be seen from provided code), the variables were not being passed globally even though they were being declared globally, and the column variables and data variables needed to be renamed.